# 3-Layer without repositories, with entity framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I've decided to ditch repositories, instead I will use them directly in my services. However, I am now not sure where my EF DbContext should sit and where *SaveChanges()* should be called from. Here is my current design:

- **MVC Client**

  - View Models
- **Core** BLL

  - Domain Models
  - Managers
  - Services - *Used to talk to third-parties and DAL*
- **Data** DAL

  - Entity Models
  - DbContext

Should services sit in BLL, or should that be in the DAL?

Also any improvements you could suggest on the above are welcome, thank you!

Comment: You don't really have a full design pattern here. You've taken the MVC, 3 tier pattern and said "I don't like repositories, so I'm getting rid of them" and then tried to keep the rest of the structure in place. That won't work. I'd encourage you to take a look at what specific problems you're trying to solve, and then see what design patterns will best solve those problems. As it is, you haven't provided enough information for a useful answer.

Comment: @Necoras What am I missing if I choose not to go with repositories, can't the services speak to my dbcontext and that's that?

Comment: Since the services are used to "talk" with the DAL, you should obviously put the SaveChanges there and call the relevant service function from the Managers. I would also advise you to consider injecting the services into the Core BLL, so you can change the implementation if you want to.
I am not quite sure why you don't want to use repositories. It seems that you want to use the services as repositories and also delegate them some additional functionality. This might work well for a small project, but it will get harder to maintain for a larger one.

Comment: @djvuk So if I was to add repositories then I would also require UnitOfWork? I guess my biggest concern is the lack of deferred execution, or to prevent that do you have the query as a function in the repository, i.e GetByName(name). If that's the case wouldn't you have the exact same function in the service that just calls the function is the repository? Wouldn't that just be unnecessary abstraction?

Comment: @JacobMason If your concern is just deferred execution then you should just have your repositories *always* return IQueryables. Then when your Services call .ToList the database is actually queried. But that comes with its own pitfalls: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/192044/should-repositories-return-iqueryable. Really though, it comes down to what I said initially: You need to look at the problems you want to solve and select a DAL based on that. Just CRUD? Build a REST API. Complex commands? Look into CQRS.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use repository pattern, which btw is very effective if used correctly in DAL, then the best thing you can do is the following:

1- Remove the Entity Models from Data Layer. Consider your EF entities as domain models. Your DAL will only contains the DBContext.

2- Consider using automapper to convert domain models into view models easily. The conversion must be done on your 'managers' which i usually name them engines.

3- Inject your DBContext into manager classes only.

So the flow would be MVC -> Services (where managers are injected) -> Managers (where DBContext is injected) -> SQL Server. In addition, always consider services for cross cutting concerns operations such as authentication, authorization, calling the engines, logging and business rules validation. Your EF labmda expressions must only be written in your manager classes where dbcontext is available.